# Handling Destructors in MVVM

Tags: mvvm, pascal

I'm making a Model View View-Model (MVVM) application using Delphi XE6.

Since I'm using Pascal rather than C#, I need to manage destruction myself.
I'm not sure how to handle form destruction.

My `Form` has an associated `FormViewModel`. The `FormViewModel` should be responsible for all the form's behaviour. I would expect this to include destruction. Also, when the `Form` is destroyed, so must the `FormViewModel` be destroyed. So it makes sense to handle these things together. The problem is I can't destroy the `FormViewModel` from a method within the `FormViewModel`, since this is being destroyed.

On the other hand, I can handle the job in another class, such as a Controller class. But then I have to get the `Form` to tell the Controller which `FormViewModel` instance to destroy. This would involve the `Form` knowing about the `FormViewModel`, which is not compliant with MVVM.

Have I misunderstood something about MVVM? Is there a way to do this in an unmanaged language without violating MVVM?

Comment: Is it OK to bind an instance reference of the ViewModel to the View?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your Form object holds a reference to its FormViewModel object, the FormViewModel object can be easily disposed in the destructor of the Form object.

Your notion that the `Form` object should know nothing about the `FormViewModel` object is misplaced (and impossible in MVVM).  The `FormViewModel` object is always *tightly-bound* to the Form object; the whole point of having a `FormViewModel` object is to have a layer of abstraction you can tightly bind to, so that you can decouple from the business domain objects.